Recovery of LUKS encrypted mdadm array from zeroed superblocks possible?
I have (had?) an mdadm raid5 array that contained 3 8TB drives (identified via lsblk as sde, sdf and sdi). I did an incredibly bone-headed thing and zeroed the superblocks on these devices -- I was attempting to move some other devices on the system around and got mixed up with the device names -- I ran these three commands:
$ sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sde
$ sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdf
$ sudo mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdi

I thought I could simply reassemble the array ...
$ sudo mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/md1 /dev/sde /dev/sdf /dev/sdi
$ cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid5 sdi[2] sdf[1] sde[0]
      15627788288 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/3] [UUU]
      bitmap: 0/59 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

I thought I was back in business, but when I went to unlock the device using LUKS, I was presented with this:
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/md1 md1_crypt
Device /dev/md1 is not a valid LUKS device.

I guess my question is, is it even possible to recover from this? And, if so, how painful. :-)

If the array was not encrypted, you could rebuild with the file descriptors. It’s a disk-arduous task, but doable. If the volume is encrypted, then you will need to restore from backup.

@matigo Thanks for the quick reply ... and that's what I was afraid of :(
